# Sylius - global pagination parameter

Tags: symfony, sylius

In Sylius, is there a way how to completely disable pagination? Globally? Or at least to set different limit for taxon/category page? Default is 9, but I need to set it to different number...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sylius_grid:
    grids:
        sylius_shop_product:
            limits: ~
```

Source: https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.6/components_and_bundles/bundles/SyliusGridBundle/your_first_grid.html#pagination

Answer (score 0):

```
sylius_grid:
    grids:
        sylius_shop_product:
            limits: [10,20,30]
```